# How to assemble packets from an Observable into a new Observable?

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming

My application subscribes to an `Observable<Timestamped<byte[]>>` of data packets arriving in sequence, and assembles them into larger frames. It must examine each packet to find the "Start of Frame" header and do some minor processing to assemble the packets into a valid frame.

How can I create a new `Observable<Frame>` that will emit these completed frames to a `Subscriber`?

Update: the suggested answer doesn't want to work for me. Some details:

1. My source `Observable` emits `Timestamped<byte[]>` packets.
2. Desired Output is an `Observable` of `DataFrame` objects, each including the data from several packets along with some other fields.
3. I have a class `FrameAssembler` with a method `DataFrame receivePacket( Timestamped<byte[]> packet )`. It returns `null` until it has assembled a frame, which it then returns and gets ready for the next one.

I can't create the output Observable. I'm trying this

```
Observable<DataFrame> source = Observable
    .just( new Timestamped<byte[]>(100, new byte[10]) ) // sample packet
    .scan( new FrameAssembler(), (acc, packet) -> acc.receivePacket( packet ))  
    .filter( frame -> frame != null )
```

but the lambda is underlined, with the message "Bad return type in lambda expression: DataFrame cannot be converted to TestScan.FrameAssembler".

I'm thoroughly stumped by this. What is `acc` and what's it doing there? Why does it want to convert the `DataFrame` returned by `receivePacket` into `FrameAssembler`? And why is `new FrameAssembler()` used as the first argument to `scan()`?

Comment: Am I being dinged for not researching this? The sad truth is that I have done little else for the past couple of weeks except try to educate myself on this new Reactive paradigm. I even bought the book "Reactive Programming with RxJava" but can't find my answer in there. Is there a merciful soul out there who knows?

Comment: This problem resembles the splitting of a virtual concatenation and splitting of strings through a regexp in RxJavaString library. You need a custom operator to control the excess and leftovers: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaString/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/internal/operators/ObservableSplit.java you can replace string with byte[] and work out the concatenation and split logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get the proposed solution using the `scan()` operator to work. I believe the problem was the `null` being returned until a complete set of packets was received. Observable operator chains don't seem to like nulls.

How I solved it: 
In the `onNext()` handler of the data packet Observable subscription:

```
Thread.currentThread().setPriority( DATA_RX_PRIORITY );
packetArrayList = DataOps.addPacket( packetArrayList, dataPacket );
if( packetArrayList != null ) {  // we have a new complete packet buffer
    DataOps.DataFrame frameReturned = DataOps.pBuf2dFrame( packetArrayList );
    frameRelayer.onNext( frameReturned ); // send the new frame to the BehaviorSubject
}
```

The `addPacket()` routine adds each received packet to an `ArrayList`, but returns `null` *except when a complete Frame's packets have been accumulated*, when it returns the filled `ArrayList`.

When a non-null `ArrayList` is received, the `pBuf2dFrame()` method parses the packets and assembles them into a new `DataFrame` object. 
Then comes the trick that converts the Observable of packets into an Observable of DataFrames: `frameRelayer` is a `BehaviorSubject` (an RxJava object that can function as both an Observable and a Subscriber). All you have to do is call its `onNext()` method with the new `DataFrame` to have it passed on to any Subscribers to `frameRelayer`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the 2-parameter `scan` operator:

```
  class ByteAccumulator {
     private byte[] buffer = ...
     public byte[] receivePacket(byte[] receivedPacket) {
        // add the received packet to the buffer
        if(containsFullFrame(buffer)) {
            return extractFrameAndTrimBuffer();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
     }
  }

  Observable<byte[]> source = ...
  source.scan(new ByteAccumulator(), ByteAccumulator::receivePacket)
        .filter(frame -> frame != null)
        ...
```

Edit: You need an intermediate class to adapt your `FrameAssembler` to what `scan` expects:

```
public FrameScanner {
  private final FrameAssembler assembler;
  private final DataFrame frame;
  public FrameScanner() {this(new FrameAssembler(), null);}
  public FrameScanner(FrameAssembler assembler,DataFrame frame) {
    this.frame=frame; this.assembler=assembler;
  }
  public getFrame() {return frame;}
  public FrameScanner scan(Timestamped<byte[]> nextBytes) {
    return new FrameScanner(assembler, assembler.receivePacker(nextBytes));
  }
}
```

Now you should be able to use it like this:

```
.scan(new FrameScanner(), FrameScanner::scan)
.map(FrameScanner::getFrame)
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
```

Hmm... now that I think about it, instead of the abofethis might also work:

```
FrameAssembler assembler=new FrameAssembler();
...
.scan((DataFrame)null, (ignore, packet) -> assembler.receivePacket( packet))
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
```

Comment: Great tip, thank you—I'm studying. One possible issue: my Source Observable never completes—I have to examine each incoming packet looking for a "Start of Frame" header, and when I see one, finish assembling the _previous_ frame and emit it to the consumer. I can probably work that out, though.

Comment: OK, the `Observable` spec says that the first parameter for `.scan()` is the Initial Value emitted. How does your `new ByteAccumulator()` accomplish that? Why shouldn't the initial value just be `null`?

Comment: I've been trying to adapt this and am getting an error that non-static method receivePacket() cannot be referenced from a static context. Can you help me understand?

Comment: A: If your frame consists of several packets, then you will need to collect multiple byte arrays. Emit-and-remove the frame from the buffer as soon as you are able to determine that it's complete (if you have a size property in there f.e.). The initial value of the byte buffer could be anything. B: instead of `ByteAccumulator::receivePacket`, use `(acc, packet) -> acc.receivePacket(packet)`.

Comment: Boy, I must have some fundamental misunderstanding, possibly made worse by the fact that the documentation of the `scan()` operator is confusing (see [link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5143)). Please see my updated question for details.